# given original image resolution, how to calculate new resolution using javascript, after scaling it?

Tags: javascript, html, image, imagemagick, resolution

I have an image fetched from the server and I know how to get the image's resolution from the server (using ImageMagick resolution). So this resolution is the image DPI from imageMagick.

When the user uploads an image, I tell the user what the image's resolution is, and they can now play around with the image and scale it. Now when an image gets scaled, resolution naturally changes. So if I have a 300dpi image and the user scales it bigger, the resolution gets less. If he scales it smaller, the resolution increases. Whatever he does, when he's finished with the image, I have to tell him the new resolution.

Is there any javascript library or any client-side way to determine the new resolution after scaling? Or is the best solution simply ajax again - to send the image back to the server and get the new resolution? I want to avoid this for purposes of speed.

Comment: So, you want to calculate the *Density* of the resized image? What real world size should it be?

Comment: Real world size isn't definite, it's up to the user to scale it as he wishes. I just want to know what the dpi will be after scaling. (It won't remain the same as the original DPI that imageMagick calculated, right?)

Comment: Well DPI is always correlated to a real world size - otherwise it has no meaning. If the user scales the image to twice its size, the DPI depends on how you want to print it - if you want to print it with the same real world measures DPI doubles, if you want to print it twice its size DPI stays the same. I hope you can follow my reasoning?

Comment: Then perhaps DPI is not the right word to use? Should I use PPI? (I know there are loads of articles explaining the difference but they don't help my confusion). Putting it simply, what I intend to refer to is that thing that happens when you scale a photo to twice its size - it usually gets blurry, and in layman's terms we'd say "the resolution is bad, the image isn't sharp". That's what I'm aiming at calculating. So when a user scales the image to twice its size, does that measure (supposing it's PPI) get halved? I'm just looking for a way to calculate that.

Comment: Actually, it's the other way round. If you scale up an image, the resolution increases. If you scale it down, the resolution decreases. To calculate the resolution after scaling, try `new_dpi = original_dpi * new_size / original_size`. `size` is the pixel size in either dimension.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be the kind of calculation I was looking for, albeit in Flex:

http://blog.mediarain.com/2009/09/calculating-image-resolutions-in-flex/